# Inter-class communication in Android

Tags: android, class, communication

I have a class (in Android) called `TCPClient` which receives a string from the server. I need to send this to a function `printmsg` in class `Showmsg`, which is in the same package as `TCPClient`.
The following code doesn't work.

```
public class TCPClient implements Runnable {  
    ..   
    ..  
    public void run() {  
        ..  
        Showmsg obj = new Showmsg();  
        obj.printmsg("Hello");  
    }  
}
```

In class `Showmsg`:

```
public void printmsg(String str) {    
    Toast( . . );    
}
```

Comment: what error do you get? show the logcat...

Comment: printmsg is probably called, but your Toast is not working. But this has another reason...

Answer (score 1):

What I did not see in the given code is `.start()`, since `TCPClient` is `Runnable`. Plus I dont know how your `toast(str)` method works, but dont forget `.show()`. This code should run.

```
public class TCPClient implements Runnable {  
    public void run() {  
        Showmsg obj = new Showmsg();  
        obj.printmsg("Hello");  
    }  
}  

public class MyActivity {
    TCPClient tcp;

    public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
        super.onCreate(b);
        tcp = new TCPClient();
    }

    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        tcp.start();
    }

}

public class Showmsg {
    public void printmsg(String str) {    
        toast(str);
    }

    private void toast(String str) {
        Log.d(TAG, str);
        Toast.makeText(context, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```